# load data from MySQL with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to load data from an mysql database in javascript.

Part to load the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/layer.js"></script>
```

the script itself

```
// Kampagne laden
//$(document).ready(function() {
//$('#campaign').load('http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/campaigns.php');
//});

// Variable für Position festlegen

var left=-200;
var intervalid;  

// Funktion zum erstellen des Layers

function createlayer(content){   
document.writeln(content);
}

// Funktion zum Schließen des Divs

function cdiv(){
document.getElementById("layer").style.display='none'; 
}

// Funktionen zum Bewegen des Layers

function changePos(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.left=left;
} 

function moveIn(id){
if(left>=100){ 
clearInterval(intervalid);
} 
left+=5; 
changePos(id); 
}

function startInterval(id){
intervalid=setInterval("moveIn('"+id+"')",10);
} 


// Content definieren

content= 
'<div id="layer" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #404040; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 50px; position: absolute; z-index:3!important;">'+
'<div style="width: 395px; height: 23px; background-color: lightgrey; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;">Sponsorenanzeige von <a href="http://www.domain.de" target="_blank">domain.de</a>'+
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cdiv();" style="float: right; border: 1px solid black; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 3px;" title="Fenster schließen" alt="close"><img src="http://www.domain.de/images/close.png"></a>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="campaign" style="height: 374px; width: 400px; background-color: #0071C1;"></div>'+
'</div>';

// Funktionen aufrufen

createlayer(content);
startInterval('layer');
```

so as seen in this script i allready tried it with some jquery part to load data .. (i get results if i name a variable easy like

```
$var = '1'; echo $var;
```

but if i load some data from mysql database.. this data will not shown up

Now i found a script like this

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=       <user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
document.write(rs.fields(1));
rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

but the problem here ..

```
connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=       <user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
```

How do i fill in the right information ? what from this is the host, db-name etc

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load data via Ajax etc. from a PHP script. JavaScript is public readable and editable - it is a very bad idea to make any database connection / actions there, maybe even with credentials in clear text.

---

Du solltest die Daten via Ajax von einem PHP-Skript laden. JavaScript-Dateien kann jeder lesen und editieren/manipulieren. Deswegen solltest Du da auf keinen Fall mit der Datenbank agieren, und auch keine Datenbank-Zugangsdaten hinterlegen.

Comment: is there any difference between javascript ajax and jquery ajax ? if i load data with jquery ajax .. i get results (simple echo var) .. but nothing from database ..

Comment: jQuery is better syntax and easier.

Comment: ok but the problem still exists .. i load data with jquery but i dont get any result from database .. so i dont know what to change else ..